# Nginx, how to allow DOMAIN:PORT and IP:PORT requests

Tags: nginx

What's the proper way to configure Nginx to allow DOMAIN:PORT requests like this:

```
http://example.com:8080/?a=xxx&b=yyy&c=zzz
over TCP or UDP
```

And IP:PORT requests like this:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8086/?a=xxx&b=yyy&c=zzz
over TCP or UDP
```

Nginx also must allow domain requests like these, which already work correctly on my setup:

```
http://example.com/home
http://example.com/work
over TCP
```

For the IP:PORT requests, I tried this config, but it didn't work:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 1.2.3.4:8080;
    root /home/public_html/example.com;

    location / {
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 20m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 64k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 128k;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

---

### Added for steve klein

```
server {
    # HTTP IP:PORT ...
    # http://example.com:8080/app/?ip=1.2.3.4&pt=55555&do=things
    # there's a listener on port 55555
    #
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /home/public_html/example.com;

    location /app {
        client_max_body_size 128k;
        client_body_buffer_size 256k;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_send_timeout 5s;
        proxy_read_timeout 60s;
        proxy_buffer_size 8k;
        proxy_buffers 4 64k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 128k;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
        proxy_pass http://$arg_ip:$arg_pt;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the operating system you use? Note that if you config this, the domain won't be global: only your system will map `foo.bar` to the correct IP adress.

Comment: CentOS 6.6. And, can you explain further what you mean by "the domain won't be global", perhaps with some examples?

Comment: well if you type `example.com` it will be redirected to `1.2.3.4`, but this will not be the case for other people. The only "global mapper" is a DNS server.

Comment: I want requests from the Internet to get mapped by Nginx in the manner outlined in my OP. That is, `http://1.2.3.4:8080` ==> `1.2.3.4:8080`, and `http://example.com` ==> `1.2.3.4:80`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to have the Nginx server section shown above, listen on port 8080, not on port 80, so I changed it to port 8080 above. The server section that listens on port 80 isn't shown, but it's the standard port-80 listener for Nginx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to configure like this:

```
#resolve domain with no port or port 80
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  ...

#resolve domain for port 8080
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  ...

#resolve with IP on port 8086
server {
  listen 8086 default_server;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  ...
```

Server names should not include ports (that is the point of the listen directive) and the default_server is the one where the IP address gets resolved.

You can find more detail about NGINX configuration [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration).

Comment: With your `#resolve domain for port 8080`, Google Chrome Console shows the error `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and there's no response shown in the Chrome Network monitor, only the request is shown.

Comment: That is a comment - not sure how this is happening but it can be safely removed.  If you are still having issues, perhaps post your updated config in your OP.

Comment: steve, I was talking about your "server" config statement that's headed by your comment `#resolve domain for port 8080`. I'll post the updated config.

Comment: Do you really have a folder called `example.com`?  Otherwise, your `root` needs to be the path to your actual root folder for your application.

Comment: In the above config, `example.com` as domain name, and as a part of the public root path, is only a place holder for the real thing.

Comment: If you log into your server and you `cd` to whatever root is assigned to, do you get to your root directory?  If so, it is set correctly.

Comment: Back to your error message, does your firewall allow access on port 8080?

Comment: Yes, `cd /public/root/path` takes you to the correct public root directory. And `iptables` does not block access to port 8080.

Comment: Why do you have `location /app` (sorry just noticed that in your updated post)?  That will only route requests to folder `app` at your root.  Normally, you would include a route to `location /`.

Comment: You can see the GET request format in the comments at the top of the server block: `http://example.com:8080/app/?ip=1.2.3.4&pt=55555&do=things`

Comment: So all requests will go to the app folder?  I've never seen a request start with a question mark... where is the page name?

Comment: For the location block shown above, there is no page. `app` is the resource, and the payload `uri` is the parameters, which begin after the `?`. I'm not showing several other location blocks, for other resources made available by the server, many of which do offer html pages for service.

Comment: `app` needs to be a folder under your root or this won't match.  Documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).  So this configuration will only support requests to /path/to/root/app.

Comment: Sorry, `iptables` must explicitly allow port 8080, which it wasn't doing!

Comment: Aha the firewall strikes!  Glad you were able to work it out.

Comment: How can i do this if i have nginx inside a docker container? I set up the ports but I guess thath ports remain internally in the container.